# php insert into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I can't find out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm just trying to insert a value into a field. the value consists of text,numbers and # characters. There are no errors or nothing, also nothing is inserted.. Here is the php:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
if (!$dbc) {
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}

$dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
if (!$dbs) {
die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit(); 
}
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');

$reportdata = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['reportdata']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `onwordreports`(`reportdata`) VALUES ('$reportdata')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query or trigger_error("Veri yükleme başarısız: " . mysqli_error($dbc)));

echo $result;

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing `)` issue

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Veri yükleme başarısız: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
                                ^^^^^// close it here instead of last
```